# How to use a custom serializer in Vertx Kafka client?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, vert.x

I have the following kafka producer properties.

```
value.serializer=MyEventSerializer
value.deserializer=MyEventDeserializer
default.value.serde=MyEventSerde
```

And I have gone through Serializers in the [Vertx site](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-kafka-client/java/#_using_vert_x_serializers_deserializers)
and created the producer using

```
KafkaProducer<String, MyEvent> producer = KafkaProducer.create(vertx, configProperties, String.class, MyEvent.class);
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
SEVERE: Unknown class for built-in 
serializer. Supported types are: String, Short, Integer, Long, Float, Double, ByteArray, ByteBuffer, Bytes
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown class for built-in serializer. Supported types are: String, Short, Integer, Long, Float, Double, ByteArray, ByteBuffer, Bytes
```

Is there a way to have custom serializer in Vertx kafka client?

Comment: You need to give the full classname to the serializers, according to those docs

Comment: @cricket_007 They are in default package only.

Comment: It's typically a good practice to not leave code at the default package.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do it manually what `KafkaProducer.create()` does.

```
Serializer<String> keySerializer = VertxSerdes.serdeFrom(String.class).serializer();
Serializer<MyEvent> valueSerializer = new MyEventSerializer();
KafkaWriteStream<String, MyEvent> stream = new KafkaWriteStreamImpl(vertx.getOrCreateContext(), new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer(configProperties, keySerializer, valueSerializer));
KafkaProducer<String,MyEvent> producer=(new KafkaProducerImpl(stream)).registerCloseHook();
```

and then write the records using..

```
KafkaProducerRecord producerRecord= KafkaProducerRecord.create(topicName,key,value);

        producer.write(producerRecord, done -> {
            if (done.succeeded()) {
                // TODO if succeeded
            } else {
                // TODO if failed
            }

         });
```